# CSS Flip Card, Couldn't hide and show the contents on back side

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have designed flip cards. Actually the problem is that on annual tab's "Show Details" link is not working properly. So i couldn't show the hidden content. The jQuery code that i have written for showing the content is working properly. So when i click on the show details link, the contents are appearing one over the other. help me to fix this. Thanks in advance. Note: The above problem is occurring on mobile view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });
    $(".flipreverse").removeClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#000",
      "transition": "0.5s ease-in-out"
    });
    $('.card').removeClass('flipped');
  })
  $(".flipreverse").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });

    $(".flip").removeClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#000",
      "transition": "0.5s ease-in-out"
    });
    $('.card').addClass('flipped');
  });

  $(".show-pricing-details, .hide-pricing-details").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Show Details") {
      $(this).text("Hide Details").removeClass("show-pricing-details").addClass("hide-pricing-details");
      $(this).parent().next().removeClass("hidden-xs hidden-sm").addClass("visible-xs visible-sm");
      return false;
    } else {
      $(this).text("Show Details").removeClass("hide-pricing-details").addClass("show-pricing-details");
      $(this).parent().next().removeClass("visible-xs visible-sm").addClass("hidden-xs hidden-sm");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

.boost-your-sales-bottom-wrap {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button {
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button:hover,
.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.bst-yr-sls-nav {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  border-radius: 50px;
  max-width: 448px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn-active {
  background: #1e6c97 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button:first-child {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp .navbar-btn:active,
.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp .navbar-btn:focus {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.flipcontainer {
  -webkit-perspective: 3500px;
  -o-perspective: 3500px;
  perspective: 3500px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.premium-card {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.premium-card>.front,
.premium-card>.back {
  border: 2px solid #ffcc29 !important;
}

.card>div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.card .back {
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #555;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.flip-cards {
  margin-top: 40px;
  min-height: 2145px;
}

.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/pi-header-n-footer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default bst-yr-sls-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp">
        <button class="btn navbar-btn btn-active btn-active flip">Monthly</button> <button class="btn navbar-btn flipreverse"><b>Annual</b> <small>Save ~ 35%</small></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row flip-cards">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section1">
        <div class="card mrgn-btm-10">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Corporate</b></h3>
            <p>For Big Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>1448</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad sm-mrgn-btm-20" style="margin-bottom: 120px;">Premium Access to Marketplace Features + Digital Marketing Campaign</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm"
                href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Corporate</b></h3>
            <p>For Big Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>869</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 mrgn-btm-30 flex-lft-right-pad">Premium Access to Marketplace Features + Digital Marketing Campaign</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm"
                href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section2">
        <div class="card premium-card">
          <div class="front pad-top-10">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Diamond</b></h3>
            <p>For Medium and Small Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price mrgn-top-10"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>82</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad" style="margin-bottom:44px;"><u>Full Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr mrgn-btm-20">
                <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back pad-top-10">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Diamond</b></h3>
            <p>For Medium and Small Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>49</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <h4><span class="label label-default bg-ffcc29 clr-555">Save US$396 per year</span></h4>
            <p class="flex-lft-right-pad" style=""><u>Full Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Office Address Verification ($99/year value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Identity Verification ($39 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr mrgn-btm-20">
                <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Pro</b></h3>
            <p>For Consultants</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>65</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad"><u>Limited Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Pro</b></h3>
            <p>For Consultants</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>39</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad"><u>Limited Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you minimise your code snippet to one flip card - it is not clear which element you are wanting to flip with all that code - see [mcve]

Comment: If i minimize the code to one flip, There will be no issue. To understand the problem further, Please click any one "Show Details" link from annuals tab. There you can see that the contents are appearing under the next card.

Comment: issue seems to be because your front card and back card height is not same if the height of the both are same then that will solve your issue.